# Apexcharts - how to pan y axis scale?

Tags: javascript, axis, apexcharts

beginner js here, so far only coding in vanilla js.

problem statement: Apexcharts zoom isnt effective when there are points above charts limits.

i created a x-y charts with control limits. but some points in my dataset are above those control limits. 
how is it possible to pan the y axis scale? (to view points that are out of the control limits)

is it possible with only pure js? (i'm not familiar with angular/vue/react but will learn if thats the only way)

thanks!